# how to find the radius of a cluster using DBSCAN

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, data-mining, radius, dbscan

I'm a newcomer, and wanna learn different techniques of DIP... So, I wanna find out the radius of a inter-cluster, I know DBSCAN take two parameters epsilon (radius of intra-cluster) and min_sample_points and return few parameters back such as completeness and homogeneity etc but none of them are quite helpful for me and I also know that DBSCAN is a partial cluster algorithm and centeriod of any inter-cluster isn't located within the cluster but like I described in the image I just wanna find out the radius of each cluster and I don't really know how. Is there any built-in command in python for that?

[image: Here is the image which I wanna accomplish]

Comment: You must tell us which clustering was performed,fuzzy c means or what?

Comment: I performed dbscan for clustering purpose and the language I used was python.

Answer (score 1):

DBSCAN does not compute a "radius" value.

The epsilon parameter can be much smaller than your cluster.

A radius is easy in a geometrical model like the one you presented. But in more complex data, or with arbitrary distance functions, you can do litte than trying out every single point as potential center. And even then, this point can be atypical for your cluster.

I guess the closest match for your intuition of a "radius" is to find the point which minimizes the maximum distance to all other cluster members. I think you will have to *try* every point for this. This minimum-maximum distance is then your radius.

But again, this does not guarantee a good representative point for non-convex clusters with noise. So the "radius" may be just as misleading.

Comment: So, are you suggesting me k-means approach then? Because, this is how k-means approach works, it computes point to point distance...

Comment: I'm not a big fan of k-means. PAM and MaxiMin-Clustering may be more what you are looking for from the *output format*; but that does not say it makes sense on your data. Often, people wish for something that does not work.

Comment: I'm trying different methods in finding characteristics of clusters and on those features basis want to predict which cluster is larger and denser and for that purpose I thought finding radius of cluster could be one of the feature...